# How to change the default --color preference for "ls' on Windows?

Tags: windows, ls

I'm using ls (from Msys) on Windows. By default, ls doesn't colour-code directories and archives, but that's something I want. I'm tired of typing "ls -C" and "ls --color". Is there any way apart from setting up a bash script that will let me do this. (Remember, I'm on Windows)

Comment: This may be of some relevance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946546/how-to-load-ansi-escape-codes-or-get-coloured-file-listing-in-winxp-cmd-shell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
doskey ls=ls --color $*
```

doskey is built-in, even!

I have a startup .bat file that acts as sort-of a `.bashrc`, and throw all my aliases in there, as well as having a small Python script to manage them more easily. cmd is really very bearable with a few additional tools (Cygwin goes a *long* way, just add its `\bin` to your PATH)

---

To apply aliases automatically with each new instance of `cmd`, create a `.bat` file, for example at `%USERPROFILE%\aliases.bat` with this content:

```
@ECHO OFF
doskey ls=ls --color $*
```

Then, using `regedit`, locate `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\`
and add a `String Value` named `Autorun`, with Value data set to: `%USERPROFILE%\aliases.bat`

Comment: Um... how do I get this to work permanently with all instances of cmd.exe?

Comment: That's what the .config file is for. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun (make it if it doesn't exist), and point that towards a .bat. This means you can very easily configure ANY variable without actually making any changes that aren't very easy to reverse. Make sure to add an @ECHO OFF so it doesn't tell you what you're doing every time you start a prompt :)

Comment: Well, it does what it should, but it **silently chops off all other arguments to ls**

Comment: aaaand this is why I use a python script. Append a $* (means "all arguments", like %* in a batch file), and sorry for missing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of typing `ls --color`, you could define a bash alias:

```
alias ls='ls --color'
```

This would produce `ls --color` each time you write `ls`.

Comment: Says *alias is not recognized as an internal or external command,..* you know the rest.